# How to change user input color in javascript once they have typed in their answer

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change color of user input based on a range of numbers they input. (ie over 100 is red, 75 to 100 is yellow, 50 to 75 is black, 25 to 50 is yellow and anything less is red)

Here is a snippet of my code that I have tried so far...

```js
function colorChange() {

  var patientROM = document.getElementById("flexion");

  if (patientROM > 100) {
    patientROM.style.color = "#FF0000";
  } else if (patientROM <= 100 && patientROM > 75) {
    PatientROM.style.color = "#FFFF00";
  } else if (patientROM <= 75 && patientROM > 50) {
    patientROM.style.color = "#330000";
  } else if (patientROM <= 50 && patientROM > 25) {
    patientROM.style.color = "#FFFF00";
  } else if (patientROM <= 25) {
    patientROM.style.color = "#FF0000";
  } else {
    alert("Invalid Input, please try again");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="celltext" id="flexion" onkeyup="colorChange()" />
```

When I type in my input it goes straight to the alert("Invalid Input, please try again");

Is there a way to do it with the onchange element as well? I have tried both onkeyup and onchange

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the **value** of the input box and not the input box itself for the operators to compare.

```js
window.colorChange = function() {
 
  var inputBox = document.getElementById("flexion");
  var patientROM = inputBox.value;

  if (patientROM > 100) {
      inputBox.style.color="#FF0000";
  } else if (patientROM <= 100 && patientROM > 75) {
      inputBox.style.color="#FFFF00";
  } else if (patientROM <= 75 && patientROM > 50) {
      inputBox.style.color="#330000";
  } else if (patientROM <= 50 && patientROM > 25) {
      inputBox.style.color="#FFFF00";
  } else if (patientROM <= 25) {
      inputBox.style.color="#FF0000";
  } else {
      alert("Invalid Input, please try again");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="celltext" id="flexion" onkeyup="colorChange()"/>
```

---

### **jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/cq7n6p1g/

Comment: Thank you! Good to know for future reference as well.

Comment: @user10614817 Glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the input into the function call instead of using document to find by id

```js
function colorChange(el) {
  const value = parseInt(el.value);
  console.log(value)

  if (value > 100) {
    el.style.color="#FF0000";
  } else if (value > 75) {
    el.style.color="#00FF00";
  } else if (value > 50) {
    el.style.color="#0000FF";
  } else if (value > 25) {
    el.style.color="#ffff00";
  } else if (value >= 0) {
    el.style.color="#00ffff";
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid Input, please try again");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="celltext" id="flexion" onKeyUp="colorChange(this)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```js
const flexion = document.getElementById('flexion');

const colorChange = (ev) => {

  let n = Number.parseInt(ev.target.value,10);
  let c;

  if (Number.isNaN(n)) {
    c = 'NaN';
  } else if (n > 100) {
    c = 'over100';
  } else if (n > 75) {
    c = 'over75';
  } else if (n > 50) {
    c = 'over50';
  } else if (n > 25) {
    c = 'over25';
  } else {
    c = 'under25';
  }
  flexion.setAttribute('class',c);
  console.log(n,c);
};

document.addEventListener('input',colorChange);
```

```css
.over100 {
  color: #F00;
}
.over75 {
  color: #FF0;
}
.over50 {
  color: #300;
}
.over25 {
  color: #FF0;
}
.under25 {
  color: #F00;
}
.NaN {
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <label for="flexion">Flexion</label>
    <input type="number" class="celltext" id="flexion" />
</form>
```